# SF book series for new readers, flying cones

Tags: story-identification

My grade 4 class had a "slower readers" group which got to read all the SF while we read the boring stuff. They had a series that was aimed for new readers and I'd like to hunt them down for my son who will start reading soon. These were short (20 to 30 pages?), and very simple, aimed at ages 5 to 7 or such.

The only one I clearly remember involved two men who ended up on an alien planet inhabited by flying cones of various sizes (they looked like candy corns). There were illustrations, and one I recall showed the men inside one of them, taking a ride they agreed to after communicating with the cone via blinking lights. I remember this because the story had a surprisingly creepy vibe in spite of using almost sophomoric language even for its intended age group.

The series was a bit worn when I saw it, so I'm thinking it was from the mid/late-70s. I recall seeing it at other schools, so it could have been "a standard" at least in Canada. I'm pretty sure it wasn't Scholastic.

Any bells?

Comment: So the cones were portayed as spaceships? Creatures? A bit of both?

Comment: A bit of both. Robots I suppose, but not typically robotic. They had a ramp on the front that lowered down like The Day The Earth Stood Still, and the guys got the cone to agree to leave it open while the flew (I thought one should fall off for ironic content).